# Testing for at least 1 non 0(zero) digit out of 4

Tags: regex

I need a regex test that will test a field of 4 digits making sure at least one of the 4 digits is non-zero. Example:

```
abcd0000efgh - fail
abcd0001efgh - pass
abcd0010efgh - pass
abcd0100efgh - pass
abcd1000efgh - pass
abcd1234efgh - pass
abcd4321efgh - pass
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

What flavor/language?

Here is the initial answer before having more information.

```
(?!0{4})\d{4}
```

Comment: +1 <duh> so simple, I was already thinking up elaborate schemes </duh>